# How can I do test automation using a python script to test a c program?

Tags: python, c, testing, test-automation

I was wondering if I can use a Python script to test a C program automatically.

Suppose I have a very simple C program which reads data (numbers as test cases) from the console, calculates them, then outputs it to the console. Now I want to read data from a file then output whatever the program outputs into a file.

Suppose in the original C program I use `while` loop and`scanf` to read two numbers into two variables `a` and `b` for several times and do different calculations according to the values of `a` and `b`, like this:

```
if(a>4 && a<10){...}
else if(a>=10){...}
```

Now can I use a Python script to test the program automatically? And do I need to modify my C program? How?

EDIT: If any method is permitted, then what is the best way to test the C program automatically without using frameworks?

Comment: Is the C program going to be a subprocess, or is it a library that the Python code will invoke directly?

Comment: @DonalFellows sorry I have no idea at all. I think whatever can achieve the goal is fine.

Comment: Good question/idea - using a high level language to test a program written in low level languages makes sense to me. If the low level is low enough, than crossing the language border might be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be a bit off topic but you could try looking up the ctypes library in python, it's a means of python interacting with c/c++ programs to call routines in headers, dlls etc..

I use it mainly for programming windows applications in python using the windows api, hope it helps !!

Here's the link:

[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... If I'll have same task, I will solve it just by calling C program with different params in python. Like this:

```
import commands
params_results = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]
for param in pamams_results:
    out = commands.getoutput('mycompiledprogram %s' % param[0])
    assert out == param[1]
```

Comment: `commands` is deprecated since python2.6 and you should use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead.